# Adding Top level Bookmark to the exsting PDF using PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdfbox

I would like to add a top level bookmark to an existing pdf file using PDFBOX in JAVA.

Not sure why the following code was not working, can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Below is how the Document.pdf looks like in the bookmark section.

```
Top
---Node-1
-------Node-11
-------Node-12
....
---Node-2
-------Node-21
....
```

Java code (Part within the program) :

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:/Users/Desktop/document.pdf")) 
    PDDocumentOutline documentOutline = new PDDocumentOutline();
    document.getDocumentCatalog().setDocumentOutline(documentOutline);
    PDOutlineItem pagesOutline = new PDOutlineItem();
    pagesOutline.setTitle("All Pages");
    documentOutline.addFirst(pagesOutline);

    pagesOutline.openNode();
    documentOutline.openNode();

    document.getDocumentCatalog().setPageMode(PageMode.USE_OUTLINES);

    document.save("C:/Users/Desktop/document.pdf");

    document.close()
```

Comment: Is the top description what the PDF document looks like? May be worth separating the code sections to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: @Ryanman, updated, thank you!

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "not working". And you mention "Below is how the Document.pdf looks like in the bookmark section" - so it already has bookmarks? But if so, then your code replaces them with your own at the moment you call "setDocumentOutline()".

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, thanks, not working means it will overwrite the current bookmark.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, could you please educate me how to add the existing bookmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt at this, I'm keeping my filename if asked questions later.

What I did is to wrap the old outline into a new item. It is not possible to add the existing items one by one, because only "orphans" can be added.

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("000009.pdf")); 
PDDocumentOutline oldDocumentOutline = document.getDocumentCatalog().getDocumentOutline();
PDDocumentOutline documentOutline = new PDDocumentOutline();
document.getDocumentCatalog().setDocumentOutline(documentOutline);
PDOutlineItem pagesOutline = new PDOutlineItem();
//pagesOutline.setTitle("All Pages");
//documentOutline.addFirst(pagesOutline);
PDOutlineItem oldOutlineItemWrapped = new PDOutlineItem(oldDocumentOutline.getCOSObject());
oldOutlineItemWrapped.setTitle("All Pages");
documentOutline.addFirst(oldOutlineItemWrapped);

//pagesOutline.openNode();
oldOutlineItemWrapped.openNode();
documentOutline.openNode();

document.getDocumentCatalog().setPageMode(PageMode.USE_OUTLINES);

document.save("000009-modified.pdf");

document.close();
```